# Extracting values from ImageCollection at set of points in FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to extract values from an ImageCollection for a set of coordinates in Google Earth Engine using the Python API.

First, I set up my EE environment:

```
import ee
import pprint
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

Then I load the image collection and points. Pts is intended to be read into a table with latitude, longitude, and siteID as columns.

```
img = ee.ImageCollection('UMT/NTSG/v2/MODIS/NPP')
pts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/name/sites_unique.csv');
```

The image collection contains many images, each representing a year. I would like to iterate through each year and extract the associated NPP (band: ‘annual_npp’) for each point in pts. I anticipate this looking like (pseudocode):

```
For year in [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]:
    img_selection = img.select(year = yr)
    output = img_selection.sample(pts, 1000).get('annual_npp').getInfo()
```

Does anyone know a generalizable way to extract this information from an ImageCollection?

**Edit**
I get something close to the intended outcome in Earth Engine using the following:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UMT/NTSG/v2/MODIS/NPP')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2013-01-01'));
var npp = dataset.select('annualNPP').mean();
var out = npp.select(['annualNPP']).sampleRegions({
  collection: pts,
  properties: ['SiteID'],
  geometries: true,
  scale: 1000
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def sample_point(point, image):
    return image \
        .select(['annualNPP']) \
        .sample(
            region=point.geometry(),
            scale=1000, 
            numPixels=1
        ) \
        .first() \
        .set('year', image.date().get('year')) \
        .set('point', point.geometry().coordinates())


def sample_image(image):
    return pts.map(lambda point: sample_point(point, image))


img = ee.ImageCollection('UMT/NTSG/v2/MODIS/NPP')
pts = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-100, 35])),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-100, 40]))
])

dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UMT/NTSG/v2/MODIS/NPP') \
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2013-01-01'))

nppFeatures = dataset \
    .map(sample_image) \
    .flatten()

npp = [feature.get('properties') for feature in nppFeatures.getInfo().get('features')]

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(npp)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Daniel!